# How to add flutter radio button with right side of image

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm beginner for the flutter and I'm try to added radio button with right side to images , but its not working correctly, anyone know how to do that correctly

[image: Image description]

Thanks

**here the code**

```
  Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration( borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                  border: Border.all(      color: Color(0xFFD8D8D8),)
                              ),
                              child:  Column( mainAxisAlignment:
                              MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  ListTile(
                                    title: const Text('Debit Card'),
                                    leading: Radio<SingingCharacter>(
                                      value: SingingCharacter.lafayette,
                                      groupValue: _character,
                                      onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          _character = value;
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  ListTile(
                                    title: const Text('Credit Card'),
                                    leading: Radio<SingingCharacter>(
                                      value: SingingCharacter.jefferson,
                                      groupValue: _character,
                                      onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          _character = value;
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),

                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think you use RadioListTile try to below answer Hope it help.

```
   enum SingingCharacter { one, two }
   SingingCharacter? _character = SingingCharacter.one;

  //Your Widget
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        RadioListTile<SingingCharacter>(
          title: const Text('Credit Card'),
          value: SingingCharacter.one,
          groupValue: _character,
          onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
            setState(() {
              _character = value;
            });
          },
        ),
        RadioListTile<SingingCharacter>(
          title: const Text('Debit Card'),
          value: SingingCharacter.two,
          groupValue: _character,
          onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
            setState(() {
              _character = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Or You Add this Radio Button on right side of the Name Just use the trailing in Listview insted of leading.

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    ListTile(
      title: const Text('Credit Card'),
      trailing: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
      leading: Radio<SingingCharacter>(
        value: SingingCharacter.one,
        groupValue: _character,
        onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
          setState(() {
            _character = value;
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: const Text('Debit Card'),
      trailing: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
      leading: Radio<SingingCharacter>(
        value: SingingCharacter.two,
        groupValue: _character,
        onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
          setState(() {
            _character = value;
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Your Screen using RadioListTile -> [image]

Your screen using ListTile with image [image]

Comment: any idea for, 2nd radio button not clickable? what is he reason?

Comment: Do you have try my code both radio buttons are worked very well,

Comment: Yes, something wrong with my code I will check , anyway thanks for the help

Comment: @core114, Ok Most Welcome

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
ListTile(
             title: const Text('Debit Card'),
             trailing: Radio(  // type code here
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use a RadioListTile Instead of a ListTile

```
RadioListTile<SingingCharacter>(
  title: Text('Credit Card'),
  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,//**this will help align the control to the right**
    value: SingingCharacter.jefferson,
    groupValue: _character,
    onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
      setState(() {
        _character = value;
      });
);
```